# Python - collect output of recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a function designed to flatten a json. The function works recursively - if a key, value pair's value is *not* a json, the key,value pair is returned, otherwise, the function is called again on the value:

```
def flatten_json(j):
    for k, v in j.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_json(v)
        else:
            yield (k,v)

flat_json = {x[0]: x[1] for x in flatten_json(j)}
```

The idea being that whenever the function `yield`s a tuple, it is collected into the flat_json dict. As it stands, nested outputs are ignored - only the top level key, value pairs appear in flat_json.

Comment: do the nested keys need to be prefixed with their "parent" keys somehow? or just appear as-as in the flat_json as top level keys with the same name?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 No, they don't, so, for example: `{'foo': 'bar, 'foo1': 'bar1', 'nest1': {'foo2': 'bar2'}}` should return `{'foo': 'bar, 'foo1': 'bar1', 'foo2': 'bar2'}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) is for :), to yield elements one by one from calling a generator from within a generator (whether that is a recursive call or not).

try:

```py
def flatten_json(j):
    for k, v in j.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from flatten_json(v)
        else:
            yield (k,v)


j = {'foo': 'bar', 'foo1': 'bar1', 'nest1': {'foo2': 'bar2'}}
flat_json = {x[0]: x[1] for x in flatten_json(j)}
print(flat_json)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'foo1': 'bar1', 'foo2': 'bar2'}
```

running example here: https://ideone.com/Z5aO9V

Answer (score 0):

Yield it like the normal data:

```
yield (k, flatten_json(v))
```